# Trouble with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem with a for loop. In the script, I use a text list to build a URL and then ran a `for` loop for each element of the list. After having all the URLs I want to extract information from the website. That's where I have a problem.

I checked the program and it's building the correct URL but I don't know how to extract the information for all elements of the look using just the 1st URL.

Please, anyone have an idea where I'm going wrong?

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

date = date = (time.strftime('%Y%m%d'))


symbolslist = open('pistas.txt').read().split()


for symbol in symbolslist:
  url = "http://trackinfo.com/entries-race.jsp?raceid=" + symbol + "$" + date +"A01"
  htmltext = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
  names=soup.findAll('a',{'href':re.compile("dog")})
  for name in names:
      results = ' '.join(name.string.split())
      print results
```

and that is the text list:

```
GBM
GBR
GCA
GDB
GSP
GDQ
GEB
```

Comment: is the for indentation it right? or typo?

Comment: of course, it's typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei man, try this:

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

date = (time.strftime('%Y%m%d'))


symbolslist = open('pistas.txt').read().split()


for symbol in symbolslist:
  url = "http://trackinfo.com/entries-race.jsp?raceid=" + symbol + "$" + date +"A01"
  htmltext = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
  names=htmltext.findAll('a',{'href':re.compile("dog")})
  for name in names:
    results = ' '.join(name.string.split())
    print results
```